# How to handle conditional logic in questionnaires?

Tags: forms, webforms

I am working on an UI for creating Questionnaires.It should work like this:I have a saved list of preset questions. I can create a questionnaire template which can be triggered by the user at a later stage.While creating a new questionnaire template, I can either add questions from the preset question list or add a new question specific to the questionnaire.According to the current behaviour,when the questionnaire is triggered by a user, the questions will be asked in the sequence I added questions to the template.

Now, I need to add conditional logic to the questions. By conditional logic, I have to meet the following two requirements :
1. Whether the particular question should be asked or not?
2. A trigger based on the response for the question.

I am confused how to handle the conditional logic part. 
1.Should I allow the user to set up the conditional logic at a question level? If so, I have to set up the conditions to be satisfied for triggering this question, the actions that has to be done based on the response for the question.
2.Should I handle this at a questionnaire level? I add all the needed questions to the template and I allow the user to have another section say Properties,where he has to set up all the conditional logic coming inside the template. ed: If Ans of Question1 = Yes and Ans of Question2 = No Trigger  Email. (I find this to be highly complicated)

Comment: You should allow the user to specify this on question level, this is standard practice followed by all major survey platforms. The other way around will be confusing and instead of checking the question you are interested with you will need to use whole another page full of properties etc.

Comment: Ideally, there will be a sequence of questions which will be triggered one at a time. The conditional logic will result in taking a detour from the main sequence and coming back to the next question or triggering an action. If I am planning to define logic at question level, I will have to define two things:  1.Conditions to be satisfied to trigger the question. 2.Actions to be done based on the response to the question. I am dubious about handling these to at a question level.

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes the most sense to handle "A sequence of questions which interact with each other" as a single "question block" handled at the time of making the question. So, when you are creating the question you could have a button "add dependent question" which allows you to add something which only appears when the user selects a certain option for the first question. This would allow a sequence where a question like "Did you like X? Yes/No" followed by "What did you like?" or "What didn't you like?" depending on their answer. The "Question block" format could also just include things frequently asked together, such as a "Demographics" block including Age, Gender, etc.

On the other hand, "Actions triggered based on the response" seems like something which should be handled per-form. So at the end of template creation you could have "add completion action" to select from the options for something that should happen when the form is completed, and when adding an action there could be an "add condition" option to choose questions and the required responses to trigger the action.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. Allow a "question block" to be zero, one, or more questions and your users should be able to describe any path. Also allow them to be nested. Finally, it would probably help to generate a flow chart of the whole survey.

Answer (score 0):

The best sequence is to add your own proposed question and then put two answers. such that if the answer is let's say; positive. create an argument and then trigger an email. and vise versa.

Comment: Could you please explain "two answers"?

Comment: for example: to trigger a support form, add  selection in a form like; support and payment department. so if a user  selects support and submits the form, a support form will load and they ask what they want. and vise-versa